# Extract credible intervals for robust correlations in R

Tags: r, correlation, confidence-interval, robust, credible-interval

I currently know how to use `pbcor` from the `WRS2` package to extract robust correlations. This function calculates the 95% bootstrap confidence intervals around the estimated robust correlation. For consistency with the rest of my analyses and manuscript, I need to extract credible intervals instead of confidence intervals.

How can I extract the 95% **credible intervals**, instead of the **95% confidence intervals?** Is there a way to do this using `pbcor`?

My dataset contains 210 observations, but here is a subset of the data:

```
Individual  varA    varB
1   2.9380842   0.09896456
2   2.9380842   -1.38772037
3   -0.6879859  -2.41310243
4   -0.6879859  0.55722346
5   -2.3129564  -1.34140699
6   -2.3129564  -1.75604301
7   -0.4937431  0.78381085
8   -0.4937431  0.38320385
9   -0.8558126  0.82125672
10  -0.8558126  0.06346062
11  -0.9211026  -1.67170174
```

Corresponding code:

```
WRS2::pbcor(data$varA, data$varB, ci=TRUE, nboot=1000, beta=0.1) 
>robust correlation coefficient: 0.275
>test statistic: 0.8582
>p-value:0.41307
>bootstrap CI: [-0.3564; 0.7792]
```

Comment: Compared to the standard 95% CI, the boot-strapped CI that WRS2 gives should be a good candidate as a credible CI. Why not use that? Could you expand on your objective?

Comment: @sreedta I added some details above. The short of it is that I need to have the outputs be consistent across analyses (where I present bayesian methods).

Comment: If you're willing to treat the bootstrap distribution as though it is draws from the posterior distribution of robust correlations as a posterior distribution, then the boostrap CI (so long as it's a raw percentile interval and not a BCa or other bias-corrected interval) will be the credible interval.

Comment: @BlunderingEcologist you can extract the credible intervals using the qnorm() built in function in R, along with the results of WRS2 to compute the credible intervals. These are very likely to be close to the Boot-strapped CI. See my answer below.

Comment: @DaveArmstrong The average correlation estimated by WRS2 is corrected for the influence of the outliers in the data. What I usually do I take the Boot-strapped interval and also get the qnorm(0.025, mean, sd) and qnorm(0.975, mean, sd) and compare them to the WRS2 output. For mean I take the bias-uncorrected correlation from cor() and for sd I take one half of the Boot-strapped lower and upper CI. If the two CI overlap significantly then I take the Boot-strapped CI as the Credible CI. Alternatively I also run a bivariate Bayesian regression without an intercept and get the credible intervals

Comment: @sreedta Thanks for those suggestions and extra tips. Would it be possible to show a worked example for how to extract the credible intervals around the robust correlations for the bayesian regression method you suggested?

Comment: @BlunderingEcologist I would say that if you're going to compare the un-adjusted correlation interval to the robust one, I would either use the z-transformation to get the normal approximation for the confidence interval for the un-adjusted correlation or do a bootstrap of the correlation to get its confidence interval.   You could also do a Bayesian bivariate regression where y has a low-df t-distribution which would mitigate the effects of outliers somewhat.

Comment: @BlunderingEcologist working on one such example with brms, Stan front-end. Give a couple of hours and I will post that as an answer.

Comment: @DaveArmstrong I like your idea there. I think that it is definitely important to show how the use of robust correlations does/doesn't change the correlations compared to, say Pearson's correlations. But, the outliers seem to be really driving our correlations (in our real data, the data above is just a made up sample).

Comment: Thanks for the great discussion everyone! The use of a robust correlation is because of outliers as @sreedta pointed out. I think the thing that is definitely tying my hands is that there needs to be uniformity with the other methods in my manuscript. I am using `blmer` to run bayesian linear regressions for a different part of the project, but the co-authors and reviewers are struggling with my presentation of confidence intervals for the robust correlation estimates while I use credible intervals throughout the rest of the work/for everything else.

Comment: @BlunderingEcologist see my note below. You can also use ```blme``` to estimate what I have done using ```brms``` - either way you can estimate good intervals with boot-strapped robust approach or the Bayesian approach. All the best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi @Blundering Ecologist

Here is a complete example of estimating Credible Intervals using Bayesian Modeling to compare against the WRS2 based Robust Confidence Intervals:
If you use the set.seed you should be able to recreate the data.Your results will be different when you go to the Bayesian part,as it should. My comments are included in the code below.

```
> ## generate data
> set.seed(123)     # for reproducibility
> x <- seq(1:25)+rnorm(25)     
> y <- seq(26:50)-7*rnorm(25)  
> y[10] <- y[10] * 2.5  # introduce outlier in 10th record
> y[20] <- y[20] * 1.5 # introduce outlier in 20th record
> 
> simdat <- cbind(data.frame(x), data.frame(y)) # create data frame
> 
> 
> ## standardize data
> library(robustHD)      # very useful functions standardize() & robStandardize()
Loading required package: ggplot2
Loading required package: perry
Loading required package: parallel
Loading required package: robustbase
> simdat$x_std <- standardize(simdat$x)     # mean and sd
> simdat$x_std_rob <- robStandardize(simdat$x)  # median and MAD
> 
> ## repeat for y
> simdat$y_std <- standardize(simdat$y)     # uses mean and sd
> simdat$y_std_rob <- robStandardize(simdat$y)  # uses median and MAD
> 
> head(simdat) # to see variable names of the standardized data
          x         y      x_std  x_std_rob        y_std   y_std_rob
1 0.4395244 12.806853 -1.7617645 -1.4269699  0.003689598  0.00000000
2 1.7698225 -3.864509 -1.5746770 -1.2805106 -1.705238038 -1.39579772
3 4.5587083  1.926388 -1.1824599 -0.9734679 -1.111631801 -0.91095903
4 4.0705084 11.966959 -1.2511183 -1.0272163 -0.082405292 -0.07031957
5 5.1292877 -3.776704 -1.1022161 -0.9106499 -1.696237444 -1.38844632
6 7.7150650  3.014750 -0.7385634 -0.6259685 -1.000067292 -0.81983669
> 
> ## get uncorrected correlation
> cor(simdat$x, simdat$y)
[1] 0.7507123
> 
> ## get boot-strapped correlation that corrects for the 2 outliers
> library(WRS2)
> corrxy <- WRS2::pbcor(simdat$y, simdat$x, ci=TRUE, nboot=2000, beta=0.1)
> corrxy
Call:
WRS2::pbcor(x = simdat$y, y = simdat$x, beta = 0.1, ci = TRUE, 
    nboot = 2000)

Robust correlation coefficient: 0.7657
Test statistic: 5.7084
p-value: 1e-05 

Bootstrap CI: [0.5113; 0.9116]  # Boot-strapped CI

> ## set up bivariate Bayesian regression without intercept
> ## so we get the pure zero-order correlation
> library(brms)
Loading required package: Rcpp
Loading 'brms' package (version 2.13.5). Useful instructions
can be found by typing help('brms'). A more detailed introduction
to the package is available through vignette('brms_overview').

Attaching package: ‘brms’

The following object is masked from ‘package:robustbase’:

    epilepsy

The following object is masked from ‘package:stats’:

    ar

> library(shinystan) 
> # gives a lovely visualization of the brms model fit object
Loading required package: shiny

This is shinystan version 2.5.0

> # in the formula below "y ~ 0 + x_std", 0 ensures there is no intercept
> mod1 <- brm( y_std ~ 0 + x_std, data=simdat, cores=2, chains=2)
Compiling Stan program...
Start sampling

SAMPLING FOR MODEL '9faff91dfca8b644fd3fe4e0f6965785' NOW (CHAIN 1).
Chain 1: 
Chain 1: Gradient evaluation took 2.8e-05 seconds
Chain 1: 1000 transitions using 10 leapfrog steps per transition would take 0.28 seconds.
Chain 1: Adjust your expectations accordingly!
Chain 1: 
Chain 1: 
Chain 1: Iteration:    1 / 2000 [  0%]  (Warmup)

SAMPLING FOR MODEL '9faff91dfca8b644fd3fe4e0f6965785' NOW (CHAIN 2).
Chain 2: 
Chain 2: Gradient evaluation took 2.1e-05 seconds
Chain 2: 1000 transitions using 10 leapfrog steps per transition would take 0.21 seconds.
Chain 2: Adjust your expectations accordingly!
Chain 2: 
Chain 2: 
Chain 2: Iteration:    1 / 2000 [  0%]  (Warmup)
Chain 1: Iteration:  200 / 2000 [ 10%]  (Warmup)
Chain 2: Iteration:  200 / 2000 [ 10%]  (Warmup)
Chain 1: Iteration:  400 / 2000 [ 20%]  (Warmup)
Chain 2: Iteration:  400 / 2000 [ 20%]  (Warmup)
Chain 1: Iteration:  600 / 2000 [ 30%]  (Warmup)
Chain 2: Iteration:  600 / 2000 [ 30%]  (Warmup)
Chain 1: Iteration:  800 / 2000 [ 40%]  (Warmup)
Chain 2: Iteration:  800 / 2000 [ 40%]  (Warmup)
Chain 1: Iteration: 1000 / 2000 [ 50%]  (Warmup)
Chain 1: Iteration: 1001 / 2000 [ 50%]  (Sampling)
Chain 2: Iteration: 1000 / 2000 [ 50%]  (Warmup)
Chain 2: Iteration: 1001 / 2000 [ 50%]  (Sampling)
Chain 1: Iteration: 1200 / 2000 [ 60%]  (Sampling)
Chain 2: Iteration: 1200 / 2000 [ 60%]  (Sampling)
Chain 2: Iteration: 1400 / 2000 [ 70%]  (Sampling)
Chain 1: Iteration: 1400 / 2000 [ 70%]  (Sampling)
Chain 2: Iteration: 1600 / 2000 [ 80%]  (Sampling)
Chain 1: Iteration: 1600 / 2000 [ 80%]  (Sampling)
Chain 2: Iteration: 1800 / 2000 [ 90%]  (Sampling)
Chain 1: Iteration: 1800 / 2000 [ 90%]  (Sampling)
Chain 2: Iteration: 2000 / 2000 [100%]  (Sampling)
Chain 2: 
Chain 2:  Elapsed Time: 0.031892 seconds (Warm-up)
Chain 2:                0.025839 seconds (Sampling)
Chain 2:                0.057731 seconds (Total)
Chain 2: 
Chain 1: Iteration: 2000 / 2000 [100%]  (Sampling)
Chain 1: 
Chain 1:  Elapsed Time: 0.032274 seconds (Warm-up)
Chain 1:                0.028699 seconds (Sampling)
Chain 1:                0.060973 seconds (Total)
Chain 1: 
> summary(mod1)
 Family: gaussian 
  Links: mu = identity; sigma = identity 
Formula: y_std ~ 0 + x_std 
   Data: simdat (Number of observations: 25) 
Samples: 2 chains, each with iter = 2000; warmup = 1000; thin = 1;
         total post-warmup samples = 2000

Population-Level Effects: 
      Estimate Est.Error l-95% CI u-95% CI Rhat Bulk_ESS Tail_ESS
x_std     0.76      0.14     0.48     1.05 1.00     1187     1030

# Boot-strap CI: 0.51 to 0.91 compared to  (corrects for outliers)
# Bayesian Credible Interval: 0.48 to 1.05 (does not correct for outliers)
# Since the Boot-strap CI is within the Bayesian Credible Interval
# I would use that.
# Raw Corr: 0.75 vs Bayesian Corr: 0.76 vs Bootstrap Corr: 0.77

Family Specific Parameters: 
      Estimate Est.Error l-95% CI u-95% CI Rhat Bulk_ESS Tail_ESS
sigma     0.69      0.11     0.52     0.95 1.00     1345     1132

Samples were drawn using sampling(NUTS). For each parameter, Bulk_ESS
and Tail_ESS are effective sample size measures, and Rhat is the potential
scale reduction factor on split chains (at convergence, Rhat = 1).
> # extract posterior samples of population-level effects 

> samples1 <- posterior_samples(mod1, "^b") # this data frame has all the values of correlation
> head(samples1)
    b_x_std
1 0.9093316
2 0.7281373
3 0.7207291
4 0.6822180
5 0.9747108
6 0.9653564

> samples2 <- posterior_samples(mod1, "sigma") # this data frame has all the values of variance around correlation
> head(samples2)
      sigma
1 0.7320897
2 0.7212673
3 0.6204091
4 0.7844105
5 0.9443782
6 0.7311916

> launch_shinystan(mod1) # launches in your web browser

> write.csv(samples1,"/home/Documents/Projects/Rcode/rob_corr_brms.csv", row.names = FALSE) # to do more using Excel
> write.csv(samples2,"/home/Documents/Projects/Rcode/rob_corr_var_brms.csv", row.names = FALSE) # to do more using Excel  

> # To learn more about brms see this link below

http://paul-buerkner.github.io/brms/articles/index.html

Here is the second model run with the robust standardized x & y

> mod_rob <- brm( y_std_rob ~ 0 + x_std_rob, data=simdat, cores=2, chains=2) 
Compiling Stan program...
Start sampling

SAMPLING FOR MODEL '9faff91dfca8b644fd3fe4e0f6965785' NOW (CHAIN 1).
Chain 1: 
Chain 1: Gradient evaluation took 2.4e-05 seconds
Chain 1: 1000 transitions using 10 leapfrog steps per transition would take 0.24 seconds.
Chain 1: Adjust your expectations accordingly!
Chain 1: 
Chain 1: 
Chain 1: Iteration:    1 / 2000 [  0%]  (Warmup)

SAMPLING FOR MODEL '9faff91dfca8b644fd3fe4e0f6965785' NOW (CHAIN 2).
Chain 1: Iteration:  200 / 2000 [ 10%]  (Warmup)
Chain 2: 
Chain 2: Gradient evaluation took 2.7e-05 seconds
Chain 2: 1000 transitions using 10 leapfrog steps per transition would take 0.27 seconds.
Chain 2: Adjust your expectations accordingly!
Chain 2: 
Chain 2: 
Chain 2: Iteration:    1 / 2000 [  0%]  (Warmup)
Chain 1: Iteration:  400 / 2000 [ 20%]  (Warmup)
Chain 2: Iteration:  200 / 2000 [ 10%]  (Warmup)
Chain 1: Iteration:  600 / 2000 [ 30%]  (Warmup)
Chain 2: Iteration:  400 / 2000 [ 20%]  (Warmup)
Chain 1: Iteration:  800 / 2000 [ 40%]  (Warmup)
Chain 2: Iteration:  600 / 2000 [ 30%]  (Warmup)
Chain 1: Iteration: 1000 / 2000 [ 50%]  (Warmup)
Chain 1: Iteration: 1001 / 2000 [ 50%]  (Sampling)
Chain 2: Iteration:  800 / 2000 [ 40%]  (Warmup)
Chain 1: Iteration: 1200 / 2000 [ 60%]  (Sampling)
Chain 2: Iteration: 1000 / 2000 [ 50%]  (Warmup)
Chain 2: Iteration: 1001 / 2000 [ 50%]  (Sampling)
Chain 1: Iteration: 1400 / 2000 [ 70%]  (Sampling)
Chain 2: Iteration: 1200 / 2000 [ 60%]  (Sampling)
Chain 2: Iteration: 1400 / 2000 [ 70%]  (Sampling)
Chain 1: Iteration: 1600 / 2000 [ 80%]  (Sampling)
Chain 2: Iteration: 1600 / 2000 [ 80%]  (Sampling)
Chain 1: Iteration: 1800 / 2000 [ 90%]  (Sampling)
Chain 2: Iteration: 1800 / 2000 [ 90%]  (Sampling)
Chain 1: Iteration: 2000 / 2000 [100%]  (Sampling)
Chain 1: 
Chain 1:  Elapsed Time: 0.025874 seconds (Warm-up)
Chain 1:                0.028535 seconds (Sampling)
Chain 1:                0.054409 seconds (Total)
Chain 1: 
Chain 2: Iteration: 2000 / 2000 [100%]  (Sampling)
Chain 2: 
Chain 2:  Elapsed Time: 0.025316 seconds (Warm-up)
Chain 2:                0.026648 seconds (Sampling)
Chain 2:                0.051964 seconds (Total)
Chain 2: 
> summary(mod_rob)
 Family: gaussian 
  Links: mu = identity; sigma = identity 
Formula: y_std_rob ~ 0 + x_std_rob 
   Data: simdat (Number of observations: 25) 
Samples: 2 chains, each with iter = 2000; warmup = 1000; thin = 1;
         total post-warmup samples = 2000

Population-Level Effects: 
          Estimate Est.Error l-95% CI u-95% CI Rhat Bulk_ESS Tail_ESS
x_std_rob     0.77      0.14     0.50     1.06 1.00     1639     1201

Family Specific Parameters: 
      Estimate Est.Error l-95% CI u-95% CI Rhat Bulk_ESS Tail_ESS
sigma     0.57      0.08     0.43     0.76 1.00     1314      977

Samples were drawn using sampling(NUTS). For each parameter, Bulk_ESS
and Tail_ESS are effective sample size measures, and Rhat is the potential
scale reduction factor on split chains (at convergence, Rhat = 1).

> samples_rob <- posterior_samples(mod_rob, "^b")
> head(samples_rob)
  b_x_std_rob
1   0.8917219
2   0.6036900
3   0.9898435
4   0.6937937
5   0.7883487
6   0.8781157
> samples_rob_var <- posterior_samples(mod_rob, "sigma")
> head(samples_rob_var)
      sigma
1 0.5646454
2 0.4547035
3 0.6541133
4 0.4691680
5 0.6478816
6 0.4777489
```

Comment: What version of R are you using? I am getting all sorts of error messages and  I think it may be because of the R version/package versions I have loaded. Before I update my current R interface (which will be a real pain for all my other scripts), I want to double check with you first to make sure we are using the same R versions.

Comment: Follow-up questions. 1) For `bmr` what are the `cores` and `chains`? The model won't run unless `chains`=1. 2) Because we would like to use `blmer` to estimate the credible intervals, should we be extracting our robust correlation estimate from `blmer` too? 2a) If so, is `robStandardize` the only way to make sure our input accounts for this? 2b) Is the estimate then the correlation (seeing as we suppressed the intercept in the formula)?

Comment: @BlunderingEcologist hi - the function for ```brms``` is ```brm```. ```Cores``` allows you to specify how many of the laptop or server cores you want to use. So for example, my laptop has 4 cores and I usually set cores=2, so I have resources for other apps as well. ```Chains```represent how many HMC (Hamiltonian MC) you want to run with different starting points. Best practice is to choose at least 2 chains so that you can ensure that with different starting values, you are able to converge on a solution. If you want to use ```blmer``` rather than ```brms``` that will work.

Comment: @BlunderingEcologist If you standardize your variables and then suppres the Intercept, then the coefficient will be your correlation.

Comment: Thanks for those extra details. Two more questions: 1) `blmer` requires we specify a random effect. Do you know how that might change the correlation value in comparison with `brms`? 2) To confirm I understand your explanation - when the intercept is suppressed, using `standardize(x-var)` will give the (Pearson?) correlation, while using `robStandardize(x-var)` will give the robust correlation?

Comment: @BlunderingEcologist sorry for the delay in getting back to your questions. I was out sick. Specifying a random effect will not (and should not) change the correlation. Random effects parameters sum to zero since they are designed to only capture the variance components among subjects. Your understanding on the use of standardize function is correct. To ensure you get a correlation you need to run a bivariate regression without an intercept and if the objective is to get the robust correlation, then robStandardize function is the correct one to use.